# Twilio + NodeJS how to check efficiently if two users have participated in a conversation together

Tags: node.js, twilio

I am trying to query Twilio to see if 2 users have ever engaged in a conversation. I query `conversations.user.userConversations` to get a list of conversations the primary user has been in, then i filter that list to check where the `participantSid` of the main user in any of their conversations matches the `sid` of the participant user.

My function doesnt work, why?

```
const checkForExistingConversations = async (loggedInUserSid, participantUserSid) => 

{
  let existingConversations = await client.conversations.users(loggedInUserSid)
      .userConversations
      .list()
  existingConversations.filter((convo) =>  convo.participantSid === participantUserSid)  // here is the issue
  return existingConversations
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `filter` method does not mutate the array, but returns a new one, so your function should look like this:

```js
const checkForExistingConversations = async (loggedInUserSid, participantUserSid) => 
{
  let existingConversations = await client.conversations.users(loggedInUserSid)
      .userConversations
      .list()
  return existingConversations.filter((convo) =>  convo.participantSid === participantUserSid)
}
```